# Apply general conditional formatting for all cells in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

With Java I'm creating formatted tables, each one is different in columns and rows.

All of them need a conditional formatting.
If cell value is a date and less than today, print that date in red.

I'm trying to use a general .xltx blank template, with a general conditional formatting for all the worksheet (this is my nightmare).
Every time I use this file to paste a table from Java, this conditional should be applied.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you should paste Values
2. You can't apply formatting 'if a cell is a date' because in excel, a date is just a number.  But if you have a table full of numbers, you can have a conditional format to cells that are `<today()`.

[image]

Comment: Depending on each column can be text or numbers... Even in the same column data can be different. About what you said "you can have a conditional format to cells that are <today", how can I do it without selecting any range of cells? Having this conditional for all the worksheet, because as I said, tables can change it's size

Comment: You just select the entire sheet, and apply de desired conditional formatting.  Then when you paste your data, make sure to paste values only, to avoid modifying the cell formatting.

Comment: But if I select the entire sheet, will it be a problem if some cells are text and some others are numbers? Will only the conditional work with numbers?

Comment: Why don't you just try it?  Anyway, the answer is yes. text > numbers, so if you check for smaller than a certain number, text will be false.

Comment: I did it, but it didn't work, if I select just one cell like `=$L16<=TODAY()` it worked, but how can I make that formula for all the worksheet? Yes I did select all, because it says it applies to `=$1:$1048576`, but how the formula would be? I did this but didn't work `=$A1<=TODAY()`

Comment: added a screen shot in my answer.

Comment: I will upvote you but finally i did it like this `=RC<=TODAY()`. It is a bit shitty cause I have a column which is a register counter, and all numbers are in red, thats why I wanted to first "said" to Excel if it's a date but well, happens, thanks mate.